# Columns that sums the last x instances of value y to another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like the following. The "HomeForm" column is what I'm trying to create and fill with values, i.e. the output.

```
      HomeTeam  AwayTeam  FTHG  FTAG   HomeForm
Date                                
9            0        12     1     0
9            2         3     0     0
9            4        13     1     0
9            8         5     0     3
9           10        16     4     1
9           14        19     0     3
9           17         7     1     4
8            1         9     0     4
8           18        11     1     2
7            6        15     3     1
```

What I'm trying to do is to create another column called "HomeForm" that has, say, the sum of goals scored by the Home team in each of the last 6 matches. Bear in mind that the team can appear either in the "HomeTeam" column or in the "AwayTeam" column. What would be the best way to achieve this using python?

Thanks.

Comment: Strictly no screenshots. We need text

Comment: Nice dataframe, but it would look nicer as _text_ edited into your question. I also want to see your expected output. No one likes reading paragraphs of explanation. Data please, data.

Comment: @Billa: Please don't encourage (new) users posting images by expanding links. Either text, or nothing.

Comment: Apologies for that. Wasn't sure how to format the table nicely in text. Will try to do that instead.

Comment: For which team are you trying to find the form for? Home team or away team?

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: Good point. Let's say for the Home team. The expected output would be another column, "HomeForm" in the example, than in each row has the sum of the goals of the last 6 games (home or away) for that team.

Comment: I understand your question, but this doesn't seem like an easy problem to solve...

Comment: I see. I'll try to come up with something, probably very unpythonic. If I manage to solve it I'll post it here hopefully to help someone else.

Would it make it easier if I create a new table with only 3 columns (Date, Team, Goals) by joining the Home and Away and then ordered it?

Comment: @Miguel Yes, that would make it incredibly easy. Is that what your next question is about?

Comment: put expected values in column "HomeForm" and explain why this value is in this column - it should explain problem.

Comment: maybe you need [rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)